# Does Node.js 6.3.1 NOT supports object rest/spread properties?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'v tried this code in Node.js v6.3.1 Cli

```js
let { x, y, ...z } = { x: 1, y: 2, a: 3, b: 4 };
console.log(x); // 1
console.log(y); // 2
console.log(z); // { a: 3, b: 4 }
```

and it prints like this

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rqHn.jpg)

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...

i'm burned out  while i'm tring to find out Why. help me!

Comment: http://node.green

Comment: thank you cartant!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node 6 (or any other current Node version) does not support that syntax.

The [Object rest/spread proposal](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) is at  Stage 3 in TC39's process for adding new features. That means it is almost, but not quite ready to be added to the ECMAScript spec.

[More information about the TC39 stage system for ECMAScript](http://www.2ality.com/2015/11/tc39-process.html).

Answer (score 2):

Node 8.3.0 now supports
[Object rest/spread](http://node.green/#ESNEXT-candidate--stage-3--object-rest-spread-properties)